# Django Bulk_create как корреткно записать dataframe в таблицу БД

Tags: python, django, bulk-create

Есть такой dataframe/table ко-й необходимо записать в таблицу БД

| id | zav_kod | kol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2002030012 | 23 |
| 3212 | 4005030603 | 42 |
| 1290 | 900013211 | 42 |

Использую метод bulk_create: но не хватает логики для корректного импорта данных :/

```
temp_data= []
for item in df.iteritems():
    temp_data.append(test_buhgalteria(
           zav_kod=str(item[1]) 
           ...))
logger.warning(f"bulk insert begin !)
test_buhgalteria.objects.bulk_create(temp_data)
logger.warning(f"bulk insert finish !!!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    temp_data = []
    object_id = (test_buhgalteria.objects.latest("id").id + 1
                 if test_buhgalteria.objects.all().exists() else 0)
    file_excel_df = pd.read_excel("documents//1c_test.xlsx")
    for i, row in file_excel_df[:6].iterrows():
        temp_data.append(test_buhgalteria(
            id=object_id,
            zav_kod=str(row[1]),
            naimenovanie=row[2],
            kol=row[3],
            ed_izm=row[4]
        ))
        object_id += 1

    logger.warning(f"bulk insert begin !")
    test_buhgalteria.objects.bulk_create(temp_data)
    logger.warning(f"bulk insert finish !!!")
```

Comment: если кому то понадобится )